# How do I see if x is in a list automatically?

Tags: c#

So basically, I have a list, and I have an empty string. My goal is to search if x has one of the values inside of it. Here is the code

```
string x = Console.ReadLine();

var strings = new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I","J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q","R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y","Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i","j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q","r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y","z"};
```

For example, if someone inputted "A B a 1" I want to see if there is a thing from the list in it (which there is) How would I do this? (C#)

Comment: *"I want to see if there is a thing from the list in it"*... Please think about how to describe a technical problem in a technical way. *things*, *i want to see*, *list int it*, are all very poor ways of describing anything

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you question. You can check if it exists using following.

```
var result = inputString.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Any(x=>strings.Contains(x));
```

You need to split the input string based on whitespace, and compare if any of them exist in your original collection. You can do so using Linq